# Necesito ayuda con algún array

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModosNormales {
    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
        int c,n;
        float lx;
        float ly;
        c=172;


        System.out.print("Ingrese lx:");
        lx=teclado.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Ingrese ly:");
        ly=teclado.nextFloat();

        for(n=1;n>0;n++) { 

        int nx1,ny1;
        float fn1;


           System.out.print("Ingrese valor de nx:");
           nx1=teclado.nextInt();
           System.out.print("Ingrese valor de ny:");
           ny1=teclado.nextInt();
           fn1=c*(float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx1/lx),2)+(float)(Math.pow((ny1/ly),2)));
           System.out.print("Fn=");
           System.out.println(fn1);
    if(fn1>=500)

    {System.out.println("Frecuencia mayor o igual a 500Hz");
    break;


  }}}}
```

Hola soy novato en esto y tengo una duda quiero que los valores de "fn1" que pueden variar en cuanto a cantidad de resultados, queden guardadosy el programa me diga todos los resultados en una lista y cuantos se repiten

```
fn1=c*(float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx1/lx),2)+(float)(Math.pow((ny1/ly),2)));
```

Esta fórmula varía en relación a la cantidad de resultados

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una forma en la que lo podrías implementar no tiene nada de complicado pero si tienes dudas no dudes en preguntar

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModosNormales {
  public static void main(String[] ar) {

    //Crea un mapa
    Map<Float, Integer> data = new HashMap<Float, Integer>();

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c, n;
    float lx;
    float ly;
    c = 172;
    System.out.print("Ingrese lx:");
    lx = teclado.nextFloat();
    System.out.print("Ingrese ly:");
    ly = teclado.nextFloat();
    for (n = 1; n > 0; n++) {
      int nx1, ny1;
      float fn1;
      System.out.print("Ingrese valor de nx:");
      nx1 = teclado.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Ingrese valor de ny:");
      ny1 = teclado.nextInt();
      fn1 = c * (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((nx1 / lx), 2) + (float) (Math.pow((ny1 / ly), 2)));

      //LLama a metodo que guarda los datos en un mapa
      data = saveData(data,fn1);

      System.out.print("Fn="+fn1);
      if (fn1 >= 500) {
        System.out.println("Frecuencia mayor o igual a 500Hz");
        printData(data);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  public static Map<Float, Integer> saveData(Map<Float, Integer> data, float fn1){
    //Si fn1 existe en el mapa obtiene el numero de veces que ha ocurrido y le suma 1
    if(data.containsKey(fn1)) 
      data.put(fn1, (data.get(fn1)+1));
    //Si el objeto no existe en el mapa le asigna 1
    else 
      data.put(fn1, 1);

    return data;
  }
  public static void printData(Map<Float, Integer> data) {
    for (Entry<Float, Integer> entry : data.entrySet()) 
      System.out.println(entry.getKey().toString() + "   -    " + entry.getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: Super, me salvaste lo que pasa esque yo no soy programador pero en la universidad trabajo en un proyecto que me vi en la necesidad de aprender algo basico. muchas gracias estimado (tienes un punto :D)